# How to debug mod_perl with reverse proxy of mod_proxy?

Tags: json, perl, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy, mod-perl

I'm new to this with a very low background so bear with me. I want to debug my issue of prematurely terminating loading the page from the reverse proxied site as it request something like filename.json file. I noticed in the request header it has Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded, and the response headers are

```
$WSEP:
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Language:en-US
Content-Length:55
Content-Type:text/html;charset=UTF-8
Date:Sun, 12 Jun 2016 04:54:18 GMT
Expires:Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=97
Server:Apache
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-Cnection:Close
```

but I'm wondering why it's text/html content-type when it's json, so I tried manipulating the response with application/json and even trying to instead of downloading the page from the remote server, I made it download locally from my server /var/www/html by creating dummy json file. I was thinking because this is json file it should be application/json not text/html as Content-Type. But the issue still exists. It just stops when it reached requesting that json file.

Now my question is, how can I make sure that requesting to that json is the culprit? Or more appropriately, how can I debug the mod_perl. I tried adding

```
use warning;
```

in the code

```
PerlWarn On
```

in the apache config but still I don't see any warning/errors that will guide me to debug.

Can you give me advice on how to do find the fault?

By the way, the site of that json file being requested returns 404 but I assume that the proxy server should ignore it and continue downloading other files.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have the experience to help, but it is recommended to use `use warnings` and `use strict` in production (or not) code.